# How many keyframes and frames would it be appropriate to use when animating a 100 moves (50 a piece) chess game?

Tags: animation, blender

I'm new to 3d design with blender. I've create my chess board and pieces and i intend to animate a chess game.

Comment: This belongs on the Blender Stack Exchange. Please do not cross-post there, but I have flagged the post as off-topic, and a mod may decide to migrate it for you.

Comment: Next post perhaps. I appreciate the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it sounds like an easy question, there are a lot of factors that you need to consider to get the final numbers to use, the numbers will also most likely change as you create the animation. The number of keyframes is the last thing you need to consider.

The first thing to consider is how long you want the animation to be and how long you want to spend rendering the animation. Start with the quality and length you want the final animation to be, and how long it takes to render one image of your scene. With 100 moves at an average of 2 seconds each you will want 200 seconds or 3 minutes and 20 seconds of video. If it takes you 10 seconds to render each image and you want a 25 fps video that gives you 5000 frames and will take you nearly 14 hours to render the animation, if you use 12 fps then you need 2400 frames and it will take closer to 6.5 hours. If you don't use reflections etc and get your render times down to 2 seconds each then a 25 fps video will take about 3 hours to render. Also consider that rendering images at 1920x1080 will take a lot longer than 1280x720 or 640x480, smaller images can still look good when scaled up.

The number of keyframes you will use depends on the quality of animation you want. You will need a minimum of two keyframes for each move, one to define the location before the move and one to define the location at the end of the move. Two keyframes will give you a simple move straight from one square to another, moving through any other pieces that it may collide with in between. If you want each piece to rise up as it moves between each position then you will need to add more keyframes in between each position.

To do the animation, start simple and improve it until you are happy. First block out each move, keyframe the start location, move ahead 20 frames and keyframe the end location, repeat for each piece. Then use [the dopesheet](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html) to adjust the timing for each move, a piece moving to an adjacent square needs less time than a piece moving diagonally from one corner of the board to the other. In the dopesheet you can select all keyframes after the current frame by pressing <kbd>]</kbd> and then shift them across <kbd>G</kbd> until you get a nice paced animation. Once you have adjusted the timing of each move you will know how long the final animation will be. Then to improve the animation you can add more keyframes to have pieces rise up or navigate around other pieces during the move.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.